# Getting null values when trying to parse an XML using XPATH in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, null

When running this code in Eclipse I get only null values:

```
    String recordsAsXML = "<vGVC:Row xmlns:vGVC=\"urn:com.versai:Bacon:GetViewContentsResponse.v1.0\"><vGVC:Column><vGVC:Value>aaa0</vGVC:Value><vGVC:ObjectName>2ff31656-b10c-11e0-99f6-e01321378d2a</vGVC:ObjectName></vGVC:Column><vGVC:ModifiedAfterQuery>false</vGVC:ModifiedAfterQuery></vGVC:Row>";


    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(recordsAsXML));

    Document doc = builder.parse(is);

    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//vGVC:Value/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }
```

I'm trying to extract the "aaa0" value.
Could you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Michal.

Comment: You did not register the `vGVC` namespace with your XPath query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use namespace context to let XPath know about your namespace, for example like this:

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {  
    @Override public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) { return null; }
    @Override public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) { return "vGVC"; }
    @Override public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) { return "urn:com.versai:Bacon:GetViewContentsResponse.v1.0"; }
});
```

This should be done before calling `evaluate`, and if you have more than one namespace to handle, you can add them all in one implementation and use `if` statements to return the right prefix/URI.

More details in the javadocs here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html